# Git commit doesn't open desired editor, despite changing core.editor config setting

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vim

I'm trying to set up git so that the vim editor opens when I do `git commit` without a message. Previously I had set up VSCode do this, but it wasn't working, it was giving me the error "aborting due to empty message" before opening VSCode.  I then see a COMMIT_EDITMSG file in VSCode for me to edit, but editing and saving it does not cause the commit to go through.

I tried to change the editor to vim instead, entering  `git config --global "vim -w` and `git config --global core.editor vim` based on other StackOverflow answers. `git config --get core.editor` confirms that git is now configured to use vim as the editor. But `git commit` still aborts before I can enter a commit message, and then opens VSCode. I'd rather just go back to using vim than try to fix whatever is going on in VSCode, since I prefer vim.

Comment: Maybe editor is also set locally?

Comment: But then `git config --get core.editor` would not say it's vim...

Comment: `echo $GIT_EDITOR` ? `git var GIT_EDITOR` ?

Comment: Apparently this variable is still set to `code`. How do I fix it?

Comment: `unset GIT_EDITOR` (then `core.editor` will be used) or `GIT_EDITOR=vim`

Comment: after `unset GIT_EDITOR` it is working as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places git looks for the editor to use, this is explained well in [git-var manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var#Documentation/git-var.txt-GITEDITOR):

> GIT_EDITOR
>
> Text editor for use by Git commands. The value is meant to be interpreted by the shell when it is used. Examples: `~/bin/vi`, `$SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`, `"C:\Program Files\Vim\gvim.exe" --nofork`. The order of preference is the `$GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, then `core.editor` configuration, then `$VISUAL`, then `$EDITOR`, and then the default chosen at compile time, which is usually **vi**.

As you have discovered, you had `GIT_EDITOR` set and that is considered before `core.editor`.

Answer (score 0):

Per discussion in comments, the cause of the problem was `GIT_EDITOR` had been set to `code`, and the solution was `unset GIT_EDITOR`.

Comment: Is posting the answer the right thing to do? Phd should get the credit for the answer, not me. But there is an answer so I want to post it as an answer.

Comment: If you want, you can change the answer to be a community wiki (no one gets reputation from upvotes).

Comment: No problem on my part. :-)